# Op Amp confusion

Tags: operational-amplifier, decoupling-capacitor

I have the following curcuit that converts a pulse train from 0 to 5V range to -5V to +5V range. My bandwidth is 1MHz.

[image]

OK so far so good & apologies if this isn't an appropriate place for the following questions.

Am I OK using a [LM741](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) (and by extension a [LM348 quad 741](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm148-n.pdf)) for this application?

If so, the data sheet mentions decoupling the power supply with a 0.1uF capacitor. Do I connect 2 x 0.1uF caps, one between the +Vcc pin & the supply and another between the -Vcc pin & the supply? Should these cap be a particular type of cap?

I should add that I dont know the electrical characteristics of the load. In fact the reason for eth circuit is to help understand how the load behaves electrically.

Comment: You appear to want to remove the DC bias and apply a gain of 2. Am I getting that right? How precise does this need to be? Using resistors means accepting their vagaries (initial accuracy % specs, for example, as well as drift over time, temp, etc.) May be fine for you, or not. One thought might be to set up a comparator instead of an opamp, apply an appropriately small amount of hysteresis to deal with noise, and be ready to consider driving an external output designed for 2-quadrants. You didn't supply any specs on the frequency. That's usually important to know, too. (Among other things.)

Comment: @jonk prescision isn't a requirement. I did mention that I had a bandwidth of 1MHz but someone has edited it out of the OP for some reason?

Comment: If you do have to develop a 2-quardant external drive circuit (you may, or may not), then \$1\:\text{MHz}\$ is still achievable without excessive measures. But you will have to pay attention to details (removing charge storage quickly in BJTs; supply line trace inductances and capacitances; layout; etc.) to get good edges. Do you have a specification for rise time and fall time at the output? The LM741 does have a minimum bandwidth spec that should be concerning to you, as well. (I haven't used one in 40 years, so just looking at the datasheet right now.)

Comment: @jonk I'll be loading a material sample, so not driving any motors or anything. I have an ADC at the other end of the sample. I would settle for 10KHz band width but would ideally like to go upto 1MHz but its not a dea breaker.

Comment: Is the material sample going to require any significant current when driven? Opamps tend to fall in the "under 25 mA and probably under 10-15 mA" classification. There are some expensive alternatives that can drive a lot more current. But they are really pricey and also boutique (you won't find multi-sources and they may be discontinued at any time -- some already have been.) 1 MHz is doable with many opamps. Are you stuck on the LM741/1458 for some reason?

Comment: @jonk Some preliminary work has estimated the material has a resistances in the 1-2 M Ohm range so I'm not expecting anything near 25mA. No reason to be tied to LM741/1458 except price & availablity. Honestly I'm getting lost in the vastness of options & my lack of knowledge.

Comment: LM741 and 1MHz bandwidth do not belong in the same circuit. But there are plenty of better opamps for the job.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm open to suggestions

Comment: @DrBwts *literally* almost any other opamp. Seriously, as long as it doesn't have 741 in its name and its bandwidth is large enough. Go to where you buy opamps, go to their opamp parameter table, and select one that works for your input and output voltage range and bandwidth. Also, whatever material suggested LM741 should probably be replaced with something 40 years more modern. Other opamps are as easily available, and as long as you're not buying more than 10000 won't be significantly more expensive.

Comment: Note that practically *any* other opamp neads lower supply voltage headroom – for example, using a modern rail-to-rail output opamp, a +-5V supply might suffice to generate a +-5V output, making your power supply drastically easier. (also, note, if capacitive coupling is an option, it's usually easier to have just a single +10V supply and produce a 0/+10V output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get much out of a 741 at 1MHz. You need an amplifier with a slew rate of >100V/us to have a hope of reproducing a 1MHz square wave with reasonable fidelity.  The 741 has a slew rate of 0.5V/us, typically.

[image]

Here is a more suitable amplifier, the [LT1357](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1357fa.pdf), which has a slew rate of 600V/us, more than 1000 times better than a 741.

You should use ceramic bypass capacitors, two pieces, one from each supply rail to ground. Ceramic capacitors such as X7R dielectric are suitable. Keep the layout compact and don't unnecessarily add capacitance to the inverting input. I would make allowance for a small (pF) capacitor across R2, you can cut and try when the circuit is built.

Answer (score 1):

Connect one cap between the +Vcc pin and ground an the other between the -Vcc pin and ground.

Those values of 0.1 uF automatically translates to ceramic capacitors. No doubt about it.